# How do I make the shape of a Kinder bueno chocolate bar?

Tags: modeling

I'm really struggling tor recreate the shape of this candy bar. I tried making a cube, insetting it and extruding it but I'm at a loss for how to do

[image]

and this is what I'm trying to make:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track :-)

1. Start with a modified cube
2. Add an *Array Modifier* and a *Subdivision Modifier* (3-4 levels)
3. Use beveled Curve with *Shrinkwrap modifier* for the topping

<sup>(I took a small bite, sorry about that...)</sup>
[image]

[image]

Comment: YOU SAVED ME THANKS SO MUCH!! as a beginner, I am so so grateful.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :). If you get stuck anywhere, I could also share the .blend

Comment: +1 for the cute 'apology' :D